# Datepicker outputting everything correctly except for Month

Tags: android, datepicker

First, here is code:

```
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            pYear = year;
            pMonth = monthOfYear;
            pDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };

    /** Updates the date in the TextView */
    private void updateDisplay() {
        String pMonthName;
        pMonthName = cal.getDisplayName(pMonth + 1, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
        pPickDate.setText(pMonthName + " " + pDay + ", " + pYear);
    }
```

when I output the date selection to the `TextView`, I get:

`null, 26, 2013`

Can someone see where I am going wrong?  I know it's in the `getDisplayName()` line (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to cal.getDisplayName should be:

```
pMonthName = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
```

The month will come from the value set in `cal`

*UPDATE*
You could alternatively set

```
pMonthName = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[pMonth];
```

Comment: The issue with that, I thought, was it will use THIS month.  Not the month set from the Datepicker.

Comment: The first method shown would use the month set in the Calendar instance cal.  If you don't want to set cal to the date from the date picker, you can use the method in the update to the original answer.